# Update list in SharePoint framework - SPFx app

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

i have created list and columns in SPFx app using elemets.xml and schema.xml. Now after doing this i want to add new column to already created list. I have created elements-v2.xml and upgrade-actions-v2.xml with the following codes i.e,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

<Field ID="{A9E2A4DC-720D-426E-B674-E13722DF9208}"
        Name="SPFxTagsAmount1"
        DisplayName="SPFxTagsAmountDisplay1"
        Type="Currency"
        Decimals="2"
        Min="0"
        Required="FALSE"
        Group="SPFx Columns" />   

</Elements>
```

and

```
<AddContentTypeField 
 ContentTypeId="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
 FieldId="{A9E2A4DC-720D-426E-B674-E13722DF9208}" 
 PushDown="TRUE" />
<ApplyElementManifests>
  <ElementManifest Location="523fe887-ced5-4036-b564-8dad5c6c6e24\elements-v2.xml" />
</ApplyElementManifests>
```

and referenced the new column in schema.xml i.e,

```
    <Views>
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="ID" />
      <FieldRef Name="SPFxTagsAmount" />
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="SPFxAmount"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="SPFxCostCenter"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
  </View>
</Views>
```

and in the package-solution.json added the following line in the features property.

```
"upgradeActions": [
        "upgrade-actions-v2.xml"
      ]
```

After incrementing version for both solution and feature, i redeployed it. List has not updated. Any help ?, where am i doing wrong ?? Followed [Provisioning SharePoint assets from your SharePoint client-side web part](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package).

Comment: Have you tried switching the AddContentTypeField and ApplyElementManifests in upgrade-actions-v2.xml so that the field is created before you try to add it to the content type?

Comment: AddContentTypeField and ApplyElementManifests  are already in upgrade-actions-v2.xml, the issue is with AddContentTypeField, whenever i use it inupgrade-actions-v2.xml , package is not upgraded and so is version.

Comment: I can see they are in there, but you have the AddContentTypeField before the ApplyElementManifests and logically it should be after

Comment: Yup you are right, logical error. Corrected and got the result. Thanks

Comment: Has anybody been able to bind a field to an existing content type (native), at the first deployment of the app (without the upgradeActions) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the order of elements in `upgrade-actions-v2.xml`, so it becomes:

```
<ApplyElementManifests>
  <ElementManifest Location="523fe887-ced5-4036-b564-8dad5c6c6e24\elements-v2.xml" />
</ApplyElementManifests>
<AddContentTypeField 
 ContentTypeId="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
 FieldId="{A9E2A4DC-720D-426E-B674-E13722DF9208}" 
 PushDown="TRUE" />
```

That'll create the field before you add it to the content type.

Comment: Hi Per, if you have any idea about how to update list schema in SPFx ??

Comment: No being limited to AddContentTypeField and ApplyElementManifests seems to make this impossible for the moment